# regexp not matching all pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regexp pattern for matching simple regexp, this can catch all pattern in text but not the first..

My pattern is

```
/\/((?:.| )+)\//g
```

My text is

```
|==== Données ====>
    byteCode =
    {
        id : [],
        tag : [],
        ast : []
    };
<==== Données ====|

|==== Filtres ====>
    *EspaceBlanc        => /\t|\n| /                ;;
<==== Filtres ====|

|==== Terminaux ====>
    $PrefixeId          => /#/                      ;;
    $$Mot               => /[0-9aA-zZ-]/            ;;
    $SufixeInstruction  => /;/                      ;;
    $Separateur         => /,/                      ;;
    $Enfant             => /:/                      ;;
    $$Portée            => /\|/ :: caractère.length ;;
<==== Terminaux ====|

|==== NonTerminaux ====>
    @Tag => $Mot ::
    {
        const nomTag = uniSem[0].toSource();
        const index = byteCode.tag.indexOf(nomTag);
        // Si indexTag non présent Alors index ajout byte code
        return (index >= 0)? index: (byteCode.tag.push(nomTag) - 1);
    };;

    @Id => ~$PrefixeId, $Mot :: byteCode.id.push(uniSem[1].toSource() ) - 1;

    @Elément => @Tag, [@Id] ::
    {
        const indexTag = uniSem[0].toSource();
        const id = (uniSem[1] )? uniSem[1].toSource() : -1;
        return byteCode.ast.push([indexTag, id] ) - 1;
    };;

    @InstructionSimple => @Elément, ~$SufixeInstruction :: uniSem[0].toSource();;

    @Instruction =>
    $Elément, ~$Enfant,
    [{ @Elément, ~$Separateur } ],
    @InstructionSimple ::
    {
        const idParent = uniSem[0].toSource();
        for(let i = 1, iMax = uniSem.length - 1; i < iMax; i++)
        {
            byteCode.ast[idParent].push(uniSem[i].toSource() );
        }
        // ajout de InstructionSimple
        return byteCode.ast[idParent].push(uniSem[uniSem.length - 1].toSource() );
    };
<==== NonTerminaux ====|

|==== Terminale ====>
    console.log('C\'est la fin!!');
<==== Terminale ====|
```

All regex are matched but this one fails:

```
/\t|\n| /
```

Source code:

```
const motif = /\/((?:.| )+)\//g;
//source is the text in stackoverflow description
let trouvé = null;
while(trouvé = motif.exec(source))
{
    console.log('trouvé!!', trouvé.index);
}
```

Result:

- trouvé!! 210
- trouvé!! 236
- trouvé!! 278
- trouvé!! 308
- trouvé!! 335
- trouvé!! 363
- trouvé!! 367
- trouvé!! 697
- trouvé!! 983

Expected:

- trouvé!! 136
- trouvé!! 210
- trouvé!! 236
- trouvé!! 278
- trouvé!! 308
- trouvé!! 335
- trouvé!! 363
- trouvé!! 367
- trouvé!! 697
- trouvé!! 983

https://jsfiddle.net/4bx7hboz/5/

EDIT:
The pattern match on  regexr.com or regex101.com.
This doens't works in console because "\t" of the not find was parsed and the pattern don't match \t parsed...
I reflect on a way for storing string without parsing words represent special character such as \t.

Thank you for your help and don't worry about language of my text (It isn't javascript).

Comment: @user2138045 [Your RegEx works?](https://regex101.com/r/hP6gT7/1)

Comment: Maybe you could come to this [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108634/regexp-not-matching-all-pattern) to discuss about it?

Comment: Btw, `(?:.| )` is pointless. `.` already matches spaces.

Answer (score 2):

After research, the strange behavior is engendred by the use of

```
var = '/\tstring/';
```

In this case the string contained by var was parsed and \t transformed in one character(code 9).
For allow the regexp to make matching special word such as \t you do to don't parse string with

---

```
var = String.raw `/\tstring/\`;
```

In fact with this solution you can differenciate \t of special caracter code 9

---

If you're interested by a regex for finding regexp pattern you can use this:

```
/\/([^*].*)\//
```

Thank to @Thomas and @Bergi

https://jsfiddle.net/matthis/9mnzda3d/2/

Comment: In JavaScript, this expression would match comments that begin with double slash and contain a slash. For example: `// This is a comment/note`. To prevent this, change the expression to use a `+` quantifier instead of a `*`: `\/([^*].+)\/` This will require the match to have at least one token between the slashes.

Comment: Yes you're right but i cannot replace + by * because this cause unrecognized pattern with regexp of only one character. I work about a way for prevent recognition of comment without prevent recognition of small pattern such as /#/g.

Comment: I see. I don't think there is a catch all regex for this scenario. You have to rely on the expectation that the code in the string doesn't contain those kinds of comments or you have to write additional code to account for them.